# Как в запросе задать условие через переменную?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

```
cursor.execute("SELECT grade FROM users WHERE userid = 'my_id'")
```

Вместо `my_id` должна стоять переменная, в которую я буду задaвать нужное мне строковое значение, но я не знаю как это реализовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
params = [my_id_variable]
cursor.execute("SELECT grade FROM users WHERE userid = ?", params)
```

Answer (score -1):

Реализовать это можно так

```
user_id = 'user_id'
cursor.execute(f'SELECT variable FROM table WHERE user_id={user_id}')
```

Comment: Остаётся надеется, что в « user_id» не окажется строка: “1; drop table table_name;“ ;) Советую вам почитать об SQL Injections...

Comment: Так user_id же указывается ра стороне сервера, а не клиента

Comment: Тогда f-строка выдаст ошибку

Comment: Почему это? user_id же можно сперва получить, а потом передать

Comment: К примеру если это бот ВК, то получить через передаваемый от ВК `json-объект`. Если django-сайт, то получить через `username`

Comment: Получить можно уже с SQL Injektion. В общем случае это дыра в безопасности

Comment: Никогда не делайте так, и тем более, не предлагайте кому-то.